# Issue with Microsoft Azure OpenAI API content filtering in the Chinese language

Tags: content-security-policy, openai-api, azure-openai

I'm using Azure's OpenAI API service, and I recently found that its content filtering for Chinese content is too strict. When using Chinese, no matter how it's modified, it can't pass through the content filter, while there aren't any issues when using English. Under these rules, even the simplest business operations cannot be carried out. How can I resolve this?

Here is my testing code:

```
msg = [
     {'content': '我叫李梅,要1个鼠标,请送去205室','role': 'user'},
     {'content': '我叫李梅,要1个键盘,请送去205室','role': 'user'},
     {'content': '我叫李梅,要1个,请送去205室','role': 'user'},
     {'content': '我叫李梅,要1个','role': 'user'},
     {'content': '要1个鼠标','role': 'user'},
     {'content': 'my name is li mei,i need one mouse,pls deliver to room 205','role': 'user'}
]

for m in msg:
    try:
        print(m)
        res = response = openai.ChatCompletion.create(
            model="gpt-35-turbo-16k",
            messages=[m]
        )
        #print(res)
        print('\n内容通过!')
    except InvalidRequestError as e:
        if e.error.code == "content_filter" and e.error.innererror:
            content_filter_result = e.error.innererror.content_filter_result
            # or access the individual categories and details
            print('\n内容不通过!')
            for category, details in content_filter_result.items():
                print(f"{category}:\n filtered={details['filtered']}\n severity={details['severity']}")
            continue
```

And the result shows below:

```
{'content': '我叫李梅,要1个鼠标,请送去205室', 'role': 'user'}

内容不通过!
hate:
 filtered=False
 severity=safe
self_harm:
 filtered=False
 severity=safe
sexual:
 filtered=True
 severity=high
violence:
 filtered=False
 severity=safe
{'content': '我叫李梅,要1个键盘,请送去205室', 'role': 'user'}

内容不通过!
hate:
 filtered=False
 severity=safe
self_harm:
 filtered=False
 severity=safe
sexual:
 filtered=True
 severity=medium
violence:
 filtered=False
 severity=safe
{'content': '我叫李梅,要1个,请送去205室', 'role': 'user'}

内容不通过!
hate:
 filtered=False
 severity=safe
self_harm:
 filtered=False
 severity=safe
sexual:
 filtered=True
 severity=high
violence:
 filtered=False
 severity=safe
{'content': '我叫李梅,要1个', 'role': 'user'}

内容不通过!
hate:
 filtered=False
 severity=safe
self_harm:
 filtered=False
 severity=safe
sexual:
 filtered=True
 severity=medium
violence:
 filtered=False
 severity=safe
{'content': '要1个鼠标', 'role': 'user'}

内容不通过!
hate:
 filtered=False
 severity=safe
self_harm:
 filtered=False
 severity=safe
sexual:
 filtered=True
 severity=medium
violence:
 filtered=False
 severity=safe
{'content': 'my name is li mei,i need one mouse,pls deliver to room 205', 'role': 'user'}

内容通过!
```

Answer (score 0):

I made a quick test using your text directly the "content filtering" tool called Azure AI Content Safety, which is called behind the scenes in input and output of Azure OpenAI.

This tool has the same result that you mentioned: the category 'Sexual' has a medium rating, hence the moderation issue:

[image: Test Azure AI Content Safety]

I tested a translation on Google:

[image]

So it looks like a false positive. You should create a support request to notify the product group team of your issue.

I noticed similar issues with French input and already seen also a feedback on an Italian use case.

If this is really blocking for your use case, ask to bypass content filtering (see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/ai-services/openai/concepts/content-filter?tabs=python#configurability-preview) in the documentation).